# Yii2 memcached not working but php simple connection working

Tags: php, caching, yii2, memcached

Trying to use Yii2 memcached but it's not working. Here is a connection part in config/web.php file.

[image]

When trying to check cache in controller it's not working instead working simple php memcached connection so all required settings are correct.
[image]

Result is

[image]

Is anyone faced this problem and what can be a reason of this issue ?

Comment: Please always add code instead of a photo of code.

Comment: as @TobiasWilfert mentioned, Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

My port was wrong, should be `11211`

```
'cache'                => [
            'class'        => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
            'useMemcached' => true,
            'servers'      => [
                [              
                    'host' => 'memcached',
                    'port' => 11212,                               
                    'weight'=>60                                   
                ]
            ],      
        ],
```